# Sequentialize files in different directories

Tags: python, linux, directory, subdirectory, directory-structure

I have a directory with this kind of structure:

```
corpus_0
    text_0.txt
    text_1.txt
    text_2.txt
    ...(so on)

corpus_1
    text_0.txt
    text_1.txt
    text_2.txt
    ...(so on)

corpus_2
    text_0.txt
    text_1.txt
    text_2.txt
    ...(so on)

...(so on)
```

I want to convert it to something like this:

```
text_0.txt (this is text_0 from corpus_0)
text_1.txt (this is text_1 from corpus_0)
text_2.txt (this is text_2 from corpus_0)
text_3.txt (this is text_0 from corpus_1)
text_4.txt (this is text_1 from corpus_1)
text_5.txt (this is text_2 from corpus_1)
text_6.txt (this is text_0 from corpus_2)
text_7.txt (this is text_1 from corpus_2)
text_8.txt (this is text_2 from corpus_2)
```

(That was just a sample to depict what I want. My *real* directory structure is a bit different. Also, in this sample it was 3, but I don't know the exact number of txt files in each corpus_n directory.)

Comment: Try to use `os.walk`, you can get text_i and corpus_n info at the same time.

Comment: So, what have you tried? Do you have some code that isn't doing what you want it to do?

Comment: @Macattack I tried but I just couldn't come up with a way to do it :(

Comment: @SCKU Could you add an answer explaining how to do that in detail?

Comment: Please add your code and then we can offer some modifications to make it work.

Comment: @WhiteWood Sure, but don't get what you want to do. do you want to create a new folder then add all `text` file in it with some suffix like `text_0_corpus_0.txt'??

Comment: @SCKU Pretty much, but I don't want it to be called 'text_0_corpus_0.txt', I want it to be called text_0.

Comment: This is what I want my new directory structure to be:
```
text_0.txt (this is text_0 from corpus_0)
text_1.txt (this is text_1 from corpus_0)
text_2.txt (this is text_2 from corpus_0)
text_3.txt (this is text_0 from corpus_1)
text_4.txt (this is text_1 from corpus_1)
text_5.txt (this is text_2 from corpus_1)
text_6.txt (this is text_0 from corpus_2)
text_7.txt (this is text_1 from corpus_2)
text_8.txt (this is text_2 from corpus_2)
```

Comment: @WhiteWood oh,  got it, thanks. you can use a counter, says `i` with `os.walk`. if sorted folder name is matter, you can get all sub folders once then sort them first.